# OperationalError (2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (-1)") - Django on Google App Engine

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine

I'm guessing that this is a fairly simple problem, but I'm having difficulty putting my Django project on GAE. Pages that don't access my Cloud SQL database work fine, but whenever I try to access a page that references the database, I get

`OperationalError (2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (-1)")`

All the other questions seem to have either errno 24 or errno 12, which seem to be different issues.

Here's some relevant code snippets:

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'INSTANCE': '******:webapp',
        'NAME': 'web_db',
        'USER': 'root',
    }
}

# views.py
def createUUID(request):
    id = UUID.create(uuid.uuid4())
    id.save()   # Error happens here
    return HttpResponse(id.uuid)
```

The full text of the exception:

```
OperationalError at /register/

(2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (-1)")

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://*****.appspot.com/register/
Django Version:     1.5.4
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

(2001, "Can't create UNIX socket (-1)")

Exception Location:     /base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4/MySQLdb/connections.py in __init__, line 190
Python Executable:  /base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/python
Python Version:     2.7.5
Python Path:    

['/base/data/home/apps/s~******/1.371736483116355711',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10',
 u'/base/data/home/apps/s~*****/1.371736483116355711/..']

Server time:    Tue, 19 Nov 2013 07:30:30 +0000
```

Any insights?

Comment: Did you follow the docs? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_Connect_to_your_database

Comment: I have followed the docs, as closely as I can. Django abstracts the actual database connects away from you, so their code sample isn't really that relevant. The docs have a special Django section at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django which seems to say that all you need to do is set up your settings.py correctly and run a ./manage.py command, both of which I've done.

Comment: What happens if you use the following form for HOST settings?
'HOST': '/cloudsql/your-project-id:your-instance-name', which is described at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django#development-settings?

Comment: That did it. Thank you so very much. I was using their 'simple settings' described in those docs, but it looks like the 'alternate settings' was actually what I needed. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer by Takashi!
Change the host settings to -  'HOST': '/cloudsql/your-project-id:your-instance-name'

```
   DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST':'/cloudsql/your-project-id:your-instance-name',
            'NAME': 'db_name',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '********',
}
```

Was stuck here since two days! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue configuring my db (Google Cloud SQL) with django in prod. Here are the settings I needed.

```
# Running in development, so use a local MySQL database.
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms',
    'INSTANCE': 'app-id:db_instance',
    'NAME': 'mysql',
    'USER': 'root',
    }
}
```